# Are there any ellipses that can be truly constructed from circular arcs?

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I know that it is possible to construct an approximation of ellipses using 4 arcs, but are there any ellipses that can be constructed from arcs with 100 percent accuracy?

Usually, the construction would be slightly *off*:
[approximation vs real](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCgSb.png)

Is it possible the there exists an ellipse where this is not the case? And it can be perfectly represented using arcs?

I imagine this is impossible. But in my research, I never managed to find a definitive answer.

Comment: Yes, they are called circles. :-)

Comment: ...indeed *ONLY* circles.

Comment: The orthogonal lines to the tangents of a circle all intersect at a single point. This is not true for an arc of an ellipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We claim that an arc on an ellipse is the arc of a circle if and only if that ellipse is a circle. Indeed, look at the curvature: An arc of a circle has constant curvature. By direct calculation, though, you can check (see [how to calculate the curvature of an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527538/how-to-calculate-the-curvature-of-an-ellipse)) that in a non-circular ellipse, the curvature varies in such a way that it is never locally constant. (To see this, look at the linked answer's formula. Specifically, focus on $\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 t + b^2\cos^2 t}$. Calculus tells us this radical expression has derivative $$(a^2-b^2)\frac{\sin(2t)}{2\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 t + b^2\cos^2 t}}.$$ Note that as long as $a \neq b,$ this will only be zero at isolated points, so there can't be any small arc of an ellipse on which the curvature is constant.)

Comment: See here for a more geometric construction of the radius of curvature of an ellipse: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455731/curvature-calculation-of-the-ellipse-at-the-end-of-its-axes/3457101#3457101

Comment: Ah, thinking about it in terms of curvature is what confirmed it for me. Thanks